# How to set particular commit to be the 'latest on the main branch'

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I've managed to bring my Git repository into a condition which I can't seem to recover from. I'm looking for advice on how I can restore the repository's structe.

- Commit *Fetch comments* contains the most up-to-date version of my work. It resides on branch *chaos* (I called it that out of frustration)
- Commit *Rather large refactor* is where the *main* and *chaos* branches diverge.
- Commit *Merge pull request #5 from Synovo/send-request* is the merge commit between *chaos* and *main*. It is by definition ahead of *chaos*

My goal is to restore (as much as possible) the linearity of the repo, such that changes on the branch *chaos* are more or less rebased on main.

I mentioned rebasing because my first thought was

1. Revert to the commit with my changes on it
2. Rebase onto main

To be honest, I'm not sure why that didn't work. Presumably because the merge commit never really went away, but was reverted.

I then tried resetting

1. Reset to my commit
2. Commit those

This left the repo in a fast-forwardable state, which when doing so, returns me to the broken state after the merges.

Importantly, all of my changes are preserved in my commit which I can get to by checking out its hash (compiles, and passes all tests etc, so it's correct)

I've attached a git graph screenshot below to help illustrate my problem.

[image: Git log showing my repository's git history]

> Before you mention it, yes I know it's a mess, I tried a number of different things to no avail.

The commit labelled *Fetch comments* is the desired commit. My desired structure looks something like this:

[image]

Some advice would be sincerely appreciated!

Btw, the two graphs are in opposite order. Apologies

Comment: Don't think of it as setting the commit.  Rather than "set a particular commit to be latest on the branch", you are setting the branch tip to refer to the commit.  Commits are immutable.  Branches are very mutable.

Comment: Ah true that's a good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix chaos:

```
git switch chaos
git reset --hard <sha of fetch comments>
```

Second, fix master:

```
git switch master
git reset --hard <sha of rather large refactor>
```

Now just `git merge chaos` and you will have the desired diagram on your machine. To mirror that up to the remote (GitHub or whatever), you may need to push your branches with force.

Comment: if this is really it, I'll ... make a screeching noise. then applaud you sir

Comment: I added a comment on how this doesn't work because the remote branch is ahead of the local branch, and would result in the original merge commit after a pull. I deleted it because I realised a force push to main was necessary. Would you be able to add that to the answer, and I'll accept

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mention that because to me it seemed so obvious! Sorry about that.

Comment: In hindsight, it probably should have been, but I'm absolutely terrified of force pushing (experience has made me wiser), so I avoid it where possible. To see it written def. helps with that though. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to make that screeching noise.

Comment: Already taken care of :P